# Create an intro screen for iOS app

Tags: ios

I want to create an intro screen for my app. This will be around 5 pages of intro and can have animated images on it. Something very similar to Box app intro screen. 
[image]
[image]

So question is does IOS provides any specific view controller for this kind of intro? If not should I use uiview controller to show on first load and somehow keep a track. What are these actually called in programming term?

TIA

Comment: The screenshot shows a `UIPageViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You can save status by [NSUserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html).

There are some open source that can help you build intro quickly.

https://github.com/ealeksandrov/EAIntroView
https://github.com/MatthewYork/MYBlurIntroductionView

Comment: Thanks for the reply. EAIntroView looks interesting. Now figuring out a way to make it work with swift.

Comment: @PowHu do you have any idea how the intro in the iOS app "Lake Coloring" was done? Here you can see it in the first 1:30 min: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTjyq9H1Y3o  I'm wondering how to create the "bubbles" with text?